# Symbols within a Neo4j case-insensitive regex

Tags: regex, neo4j, cypher

I'm storing e-mail addresses within some user nodes that I'm trying to match against, however the `(?i)` case-insensitive option doesn't appear to work when a `+` is added in the mail address. I use these to test, for example `john+business@doe.com`.

Setting up test nodes:

```
CREATE (uWithoutSymbol:USER {
    email: 'john@doe.com'
})
CREATE (uWithSymbol:USER {
    email: 'john+business@doe.com'
})
```

The Cypher queries:

```
MATCH (u:USER)
// This works
WHERE u.email =~ '(?i)john@doe.com'
RETURN u

MATCH (u:USER)
// This returns nothing
WHERE u.email =~ '(?i)john+business@doe.com'
RETURN u
```

I tried going for the case-insensitive unicode one: `(?ui)`, but also no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plus symbol '+' has special meaning in regex; escape it:

```
WHERE u.email =~ '(?i)john\\+business@doe.com'
```

The plus sign means "one or more of the previous term", so your attempt would match `"johnbusiness@doe.com"` or `"johnnnnbusiness@doe.com"`.

Technically, you should probably escape the dot too:

```
WHERE u.email =~ '(?i)john\\+business@doe\.com'
```

because without escaping the dot, it will match any character there, eg it will match `"john+business@doeAcom"` or `"john+business@doe#com"` too.

<sub>Thanks to [@Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/158701/stefan-armbruster) for pointing out the double-backslash needed to create a single literal backslash for the regex</sub>

Comment: Oh, yeah! Doh! Yet another thing to add to my list of silly mistakes made. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

@Bohemian's answer addresses the issue: you need to quote the `+`. But in Cypher the backslash needs to be duplicated:

```
MATCH (u:USER)
WHERE u.email =~ '(?i)john\\+business@doe.com'
RETURN u
```

returns the desired result.